VQE for Max-Cut: Low Approximation Ratio (0.2 - 0.5) Instead of Expected 0.7 - 0.9
I am working on implementing a Variational Quantum Eigensolver (VQE) to solve the Max-Cut problem. I am using the approximation ratio (AR) as the metric to quantify the results, which is typically expected to be between 0.7 and 0.9. However, my implementation is consistently returning an AR between 0.2 and 0.5, which seems unusually low.
I already tried adjusting the amount of layer and qubits and furthermore tested out some different ansatz including realAmplitudes from qiskit.circuit.library
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or could provide suggestions on what could be causing such a low approximation ratio? Are there specific parameters or optimizations I should focus on to improve the performance of the VQE for Max-Cut? If there are any further issues with the code, please feel free to let me know.
Ansatz Implementation:
def vqe_ansatz_vanilla(qubits, layers):

    ansatz = QuantumCircuit(qubits)

    params = ParameterVector('theta', length=qubits * layers * 3)
    param_index = 0

    for layer in range(layers):

        for qubit in range(qubits):
            ansatz.rx(params[param_index], qubit)
            param_index += 1
            ansatz.ry(params[param_index], qubit)
            param_index += 1
            ansatz.rz(params[param_index], qubit)
            param_index += 1

        for qubit in range(qubits - 1):
            ansatz.cx(qubit, qubit + 1)
        ansatz.cx(qubits - 1, 0)

    return ansatz

Implementation
class VanillaVQE:

    def __init__(self, graph: Graph):
        self.model_name = "Vanilla VQE"
        self.optimizer_name = "COBYLA"
        self.graph: Graph = graph
        self.gen_graph: nx.Graph = graph.get_graph()
        self.optimizer = COBYLA()
        self.qubits: int = self.graph.get_nodes()
        self.layers: int  = 3
        self.counted_cuts = None
        self.binary_solution = None
        self.objective_values = []
        self.convergence_rate = None

    def count_cuts(self):
        partition = [int(bit) for bit in self.binary_solution]

        cut_edges = sum(1 for u, v in self.gen_graph.edges if partition[u] != partition[v])

        self.counted_cuts = cut_edges


    def implement_vanilla_vqe(self):
        hamiltonian = max_cut_hamiltonian(self.gen_graph)
        ansatz = vqe_ansatz_real_amplitude(self.qubits, self.layers)
        estimator = Estimator()
        optimizer = self.optimizer

        def callback(eval_count, parameters, mean, std):
            self.objective_values.append(mean)

        vqe = VQE(estimator, ansatz, optimizer, callback = callback)
        result = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(hamiltonian)

        optimal_state = ansatz.assign_parameters(result.optimal_parameters)
        optimal_state.measure_all()

        sampler = Sampler()
        distribution = sampler.run([optimal_state]).result().quasi_dists[0]

        self.binary_solution = max(distribution.binary_probabilities().items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]

        self.count_cuts()
```

